# Sorting Links pramater is null when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a link header that will sort when pressed using MVC4 C#. Issue is its not passing the parameter to the Action Result when I click on the header so it always this the parameter is null. Is there an issue in my code? Where am I going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

View

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
         <th>
          <b>  @Html.ActionLink("Inbound/Outbound", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.InOutSortParm})</b>
        </th>
        <th>
           <b> @Html.ActionLink("Ext", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.Ext})</b>
        </th>
        <th>
           <b> @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.Name})</b>
        </th>
         <th>
           <b> @Html.ActionLink("To", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.To})</b>
        </th>
        <th>
           <b> @Html.ActionLink("Area Code", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.AreaCode})</b>
        </th>
        <th>
           <b> @Html.ActionLink("Number", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.Number})</b>
        </th>
        <th>
           <b> @Html.ActionLink("Time", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.Time})</b>
        </th>
        <th>
           <b> @Html.ActionLink("Duration", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.Duration})</b> 
        </th>
    </tr>
@{
    TempData["CDR"] = Model;
  }
       @foreach (var item in Model.Calls)
        {

            <tr>
             <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.inout  )
             </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.callingPartyNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID)
            </th>
             <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.finalCalledPartyNumber)
             </th>
             <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AreaCode)
            </th>
             <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number )
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)
            </th>
             <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.duration)
            </th>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewBag.TimeSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Time_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.InOutSortParm = sortOrder == "Inbound/Outbound" ? "Inbound/Outbound_dec" : "Inbound/Outbound";
        ViewBag.ExtSortParm = sortOrder == "Ext" ? "Ext_dec" : "Ext";
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == "Name" ? "Name_dec" : "Name";
        ViewBag.AreaCodeSortParm = sortOrder == "AreaCode" ? "AreaCode_dec" : "Area Code";
        ViewBag.NumberSortParm = sortOrder == "Number" ? "Number_dec" : "Number";
        ViewBag.TimeSortParm = sortOrder == "Time" ? "Time_dec" : "Time";
        ViewBag.DurationSortParm = sortOrder == "Duration" ? "Duration_dec" : "Duration";

        var query = db.CallDetails.Select(x =>
               new CallDetailDTO
               {
                   origSpan = x.origSpan,
                   callingPartyNumber = x.callingPartyNumber,
                   callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID = x.callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID,
                   finalCalledPartyNumber = x.finalCalledPartyNumber,
                   AreaCode = x.finalCalledPartyNumber,
                   Number = x.finalCalledPartyNumber,
                   dateTimeConnect = x.dateTimeConnect,
                   duration = x.duration
               });

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Inbound/Outbound_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.origSpan);
                break;
            case "Inbound/Outbound":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.origSpan);
                break;
            case "Ext_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.callingPartyNumber);
                break;
            case "Ext":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.callingPartyNumber);
                break;
            case "Name_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID);
                break;
            case "Name":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID);
                break;
            case "To_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.finalCalledPartyNumber);
                break;
            case "To":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.finalCalledPartyNumber);
                break;
            case "AreaCode_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.AreaCode);
                break;
            case "AreaCode":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.AreaCode);
                break;
            case "Number_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.Number);
                break;
            case "Number":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.Number);
                break;
            case "Time_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.Time);
                break;
            case "Time":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.Time);
                break;
            case "Duration_dec":
                query = query.OrderByDescending(s => s.duration);
                break;
            case "Duration":
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.duration);
                break;
            default:
                query = query.OrderBy(s => s.duration);
                break;
        }
        return View(query.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: You should set default value for sortOrder, or for first run in browser type for example localhost:"port"/home/index?sortOrder=Name

Answer (score 0):

Just try using `Actionlink` this way :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inbound/Outbound", "Index", "ControllerName" ,new { sortOrder = (string)ViewBag.InOutSortParm })</b>
```

Comment: @SamanthaIrenSweeney... try this answer if problem persists then plz comment... thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Could you write istead of

```
<b> @Html.ActionLink("Ext", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.Ext})</b>
```

this:

```
<b> @Html.ActionLink("Ext", "Index", "ControllerName", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.Ext}, null)</b>
```